# How do I set a child formGroup in a formGroup without the initializer?

Tags: angular, formgroups

I'm trying to dynamically set a property in my formGroup to a formGroup; a child formGroup if you will

```
// Example 1
var parent = this._formBuilder.group({
    id; [''].
    child: this._formBuilder.group({
        name: ['']
    })
})

 

// Example 2
var parent = this._formBuilder.group({
    id; [''],
    child: undefined
})

 

parent.patchValue({'child': this._formBuilder.group({ name: [''] }) })
```

example 1 will make `parent.get('child')` return the formGroup. in option 2 however, `parent.get('child').value` returns the formgroup.

How do I get a dynamically set formGroup to work as if it were set in the formGroup initializer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`patchValue` is not for adding a form group or form control but to update
the form value.

To add a form group dynamically, you need to use `setControl` or `addControl`.

```js
parent.setControl('child', this._formBuilder.group({ name: [''] }))
```